No puedo instalar libpqxx en Windows 10
Necesito instalar libpqxx pues necesito hacer un programa en C++ que trabaje con PostgreSQL (17.2). El caso es que al intentar compilar con CMake (específicamente cuando le doy a "Configure") me da el siguiente log (y falla):
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
Could NOT find PostgreSQL (missing: PostgreSQL_LIBRARY PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)** 

**CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
  Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:114 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/config.cmake:33 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (include)**

**Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Probé con PostgreSQL instalado en la ruta por defecto y en una ruta personalizada, volví a instalar CMake y no sé que más hacer. Nada me funciona.
Edit:
Logré hacerlo funcionar añadiendo manualmente PostgreSQL_LIBRARY y PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR al momento de compilar, el tema es que no logro que compile para MinGW, para Visual Studio sí funciona pero yo uso DevC++

Hiciste la instalación completa? Te aseguraste de que también se instale la carpeta include con archivos .h?

Posiblemente el error se deba a que el módulo FindPostgreSQL solo reconoce hasta la versión 16.
Puedes probar definiendo la variable PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS antes de usar la instrucción find.
set(PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "17.2" "17")

No olvides configurar CMake correctamente para tus herramientas de compilación.
